# iphone next focus javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios

I have created a code for explain my problem in jsfiddle -
here is the link for that 
http://jsfiddle.net/nxjohny/ULEDk/11/ and the corresponding code:

```
<input id="input_1" type="text" maxlength="8">
<input id="input_2" type="text" maxlength="2">
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" />
<input id="hidden_2" type="hidden" />
<div id="demo">  PFFUU  </div>

//script 
function selectNextInput(e){
        if(e.val().length != 2){
            return;
        }
        console.log("ASD");
        $("#hidden").trigger('mouseup');
    };

    function setNextFocus(){
        $("#input_2").focus();
    }
    $(function(){

        var dec = function(){
            selectNextInput($("#input_1"));
        }
        $("#input_1").focus();
        $("#input_1").keyup(dec);
        $("#hidden").mouseup(setNextFocus);
        $("#demo").mouseup(setNextFocus);
    });
```

1 solution:
If Click on the id="demo" div the focus will be set on the second div.

2 solution: 
If the first inputfield fulfill the statement on keyup(content lenght == x), the focus will
be set on the second input field with a triggered mouseup event and handled elsewhere.

The problem is as the follows:
In the 1st solution the soft keyboard won't disappear on iOS devices.
The soft keyboard will disappear on iOS with the 2nd solution.
I tried the second solution on my iphone and the soft keyboard disappeared :(

I would like to achieve with the 2nd solution the same as the 1st solution does ON iOS.

Summarization: ( what i would like to do | pseudo)
if(condition) //length of the input
then
setFocusNext
fi

And the most important part - the soft keyboard will be shown after the focus change.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Any comment would be welcome!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution is to `blur()` and then re-`focus()` in order to get rid of the keyboard.